# Using Python's match/case on repeated elements in a list

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I want to use Python's match/case to detect when there's a repeated element in a (short) list, so that if the list is of the form `[n, n]`, then I can do some arithmetic on `n` in the case statement. Here is an example, where I'm trying to calculate the scores in a dice game:

```
def score_3(dice: list[int]) -> tuple[str, int]:
    dice.sort()
    match dice:
        case [1, 1, 1]: return "3 MOOSE", 300
        case [n, n, n]: return f"3 {n}S", n*100
        case _: return different_scoring_function(dice)
```

I hope it's clear that what I want the interpreter to do is recognise that I want *3 repeated elements*, and then let me do my arithmetic on the value of those elements. However, currently that gives me an error, and tells me that the 2nd two ns are already bound.

Is there a work around that would let me continue to use the pattern matching to achieve what I want? I tried replacing the list with `[n] * 3` but that didn't work either.

I do see that this gives a valid solution to the problem, in a different implementation of what is going on:

```
def score_3(counts: dict[int: int]) -> tuple[str, int]:
    for i in counts:
        if counts[i] == 3:
            if i == 1:
                return "3 MOOSE", 300
            else:
                return f"3 {i}S", i * 100
```

However, I would like to know if a pattern matching solution is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```py
def score_3(dice: list[int]) -> tuple[str, int]:
    match dice:
        case [1, 1, 1]: 
            return "3 MOOSE", 300
        case n if len(set(n)) == 1 and len(n) == 3: # or if you don't care about dice length: case n if len(set(n)) == 1: 
            return f"{n[0]}S", n[0]*100
        case _: return different_scoring_function(dice)
```

Comment: `[5, 5]` and `[5, 5, 5, 5, 5]` will both match this case. If OP can have multiple list lengths and only wants to match a certain length then this will need to be tweaked. (However the function is named `score_3` so perhaps length has already been checked.)

Comment: You could defer the sort to different_scoring_function as it serves no purpose in score_3

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice solution! I do see that the sort doesn't need to be there, I just hadn't moved it yet, but thanks.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski yep sure. I was considering that in his case, `len(dice) == 3`. Post edited btw